# how can I exclude a key value pair if jsonArray is sending empty array?

Tags: json

`jsonArray.put(jsonObject);`

```
if (!jsonArray.isEmpty()) {
shopProductJsonObject.put("productBasedOffer", jsonArray);
shopProductListJsonArray.put(shopProductJsonObject);
}
```

```
"productBasedOffer": [
                    {
                        "offerKeyword": "null",
                        "minAmount": "0.0",
                        "offerType": "PRODUCT_BASED",
                        "amount": "50.0",
                        "offerId": "27",
                        "freeProductId": "0",
                        "endTime": "1613757599000",
                        "offerCategory": "FIXED"
                    }
                ]
```

```
"productBasedOffer": []
```

If jsonArray is sending empty array, I want to skip that key value pair.

how can I implement this? I'm using spring boot.

Answer (score 0):

Get the JSONArray :

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(yourString);  // yourString is String type
JSONArray arr = jsonObject.getJSONArray("productBasedOffer"); 
if(arr!=null && arr.length()>0)
{
   //Do something
}
```

If you write your logic in if() block, then of course it'll skip the current one.

Comment: Also, please elaborate question. What do you mean by, you want to skip that key-value pair. Do you want to skip in for loop? Or while processing?

Comment: tried the approach you are suggesting, didn't work. 

processing inside for loop.

Comment: Have you tried if (!arr.isEmpty()) ? See if this work?